# Scripting chrome console in new tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am new to javascript.

I wrote a script to automate some tasks on a website from the chrome developer console. I have to open such a page, open the console and run the script. I would like to further automate this process.

From a separate page I can use the console and obtain a list of all such pages I would like to execute my script on. How can I bridge these scripts opening each page, executing the tasks, and moving onto the next page without human supervision?

**Summary**
How can I  run a script with a single prompt when a page load/refresh is required somewhere in the middle?

Thanks, will add any further information needed.

Comment: you should write yourself a chrome extension.

Comment: You should loom into chrome extensions, they can have background scripts that run in their separate context and can have access to all tabs. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted